# How to configure swagger-ui for spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, documentation, swagger, swagger-ui

I should document our controllers with swagger.

I added

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

into the pom.xml.

In spring-web.xml  :

```
<bean id="swagger2Config" class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration" />
```

And in controller I have added annotations. When I call `host:port/v2/api-doc` I see json. 
How can I see the same in swagger-ui.html ?

Comment: Hhit `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`  assuming that your application is running on 8080   port

Comment: You should upgrade both your springfox dependencies to 2.8.0. Also take a look at[this sample application](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/spring-xml-swagger) for a sample application.

Answer (score 4):

I had to add this to get it to work for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked For me